# better to mount storage using udev or fstab?

Tags: mount, fstab, udev

I could write rules to mount storage devices using fstab or udev. Obviously the syntax is different, and unless I'm mistaken, udev is more flexible and has access to far more information than fstab.

I would like to know whether I should prefer one over the other for the purpose of mounting storage devices, and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both work for the same purpose, and both get the job done. But if you're mounting devices and only that, you may want to stick with `fstab`. Its configuration somewhat simpler plus there's a lot of community-driven support on the web because it's *de facto*, the default option on several main distros.

As a suggestion: you can use the `gnome-disks` utility to configurate `fstab` a way lot easier.